# What is the most appropriate gesture to exit an Android app?

Tags: android, gestures, close

If a user is browsing an Android app and wants to exit, what is the most appropriate gesture? Is there a standard exit gesture in Android?

I have identified two possibilities:

- Double tap on back button to exit
- Show the notification after double tap "Would you like to exit | Yes / Cancel"

Comment: **Never** ask people if they are sure they want to exit--particularly on mobile.  Instead, remember the state so they can come back to what they were doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **home button**.

> Android's design does not favor exiting an application by choice, but
>   rather manages it by the OS.
>   (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3226743/1624079)

So you can, but you shouldn't. Users would not expect a different way if their OS already handles this.

You can read more about android principles here: http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/principles.html

More about "back": http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: I have seen many people saying that if an user exit by Home button it will preserve the current state of app but in actually that app was minimized not closed. As per android if the app is in background then it will not take your phone memory or battery but practically when i used, then i found that my phone became slow due to lots of apps are exited by home button and minimized in background.